# Taxonomy Menu Associated with a single content type

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

I have a single Taxonomy used for all Content Types in the site.  I have one Content Type called "Books" for which I'd like to build a Taxonomy Menu for just this content type.  As I looked through Taxonomy Menu for Drupal 6, I saw a note that indicated it had some association with views.

Is it possible to use a view to let Taxonomy Menu build a view of terms from with the count of "Books" in each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at https://drupal.org/project/views_groupby. You should be able to:

- Create a new view that has a filter of 'books' content type
- Add a filter to ensure the node is published
- Add a views group by to group on taxonomy term
- Use the SQL count funtion built into views group by

Hope this helps